# why the API generated by AM is not invoked as the following error logs

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, api-manager, wso2-esb

I configured the API by AM and I configured the Production Endpoint to https URL.After the API was published ,I invoked it by curl command as the following.

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'client-id: vnet40000001' --header 'Authorization: Bearer a1819578-550c-37bf-8da2-6c8b197a571f' 'https://localhost:8243/1.0.8/common8/claim?vid=462cdd20-d22f-11e6-8085-f5947f55f361'
```

> the error logs as the following

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>101500</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Runtime Error</am:message><am:description>Error in Sender</am:description></am:fault>
```

then what causes the problem?

Comment: post error logs

Comment: https://ibin.co/37vVdR8zlqrA.jpg
 https://ibin.co/37vWN1LFtp0a.jpg
as the above jpg

Comment: no exception trace?

Comment: The above log is carbon.log and http_access.log. There is nothing else.
The key of the problem is that I configured the Production Endpoint to https URL .

Comment: then post the entire wire log of the request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132466/discussion-between-mike-and-bhathiya).